# padding or margin at left side of column

Tags: html, css

I am making some tables for an email. I have 4 columns: [Example.](http://vouzalis.com/color-block-4-col.html). I need the red background-color on the left to go out to the left-border. At the moment there is a whitespace, padding or margin. I do not have any custom CSS, only the framework. I have been looking in the inspector window, but cannot figure out what coauses that whitespace?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y942uoLc/)

```
<!-- Wrapper for the body of the email -->
  <table class="body" data-made-with-foundation>
    <tr>
      <!-- The class, align, and <center> tag center the container -->
      <td class="float-center" align="center" valign="top">
        <center>
          <table align="center" class="container">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <table class="row">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <th class="small-12 large-4 columns first">
                          <table style="width:20%; background-color:red;border: 1px solid black;">
                            <tr>
                              <th>
                                <p class="text-left">Column 1</p>
                              </th>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </th>
                        <th class="small-12 large-4 columns first">
                          <table>
                            <tr>
                              <th>
                                <p class="text-left">Column 2</p>
                              </th>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </th>
                        <th class="small-12 large-4 columns first">
                          <table>
                            <tr>
                              <th>
                                <p class="text-left">Column 3</p>
                              </th>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </th>
                        <th class="small-12 large-4 columns first">
                          <table>
                            <tr>
                              <th>
                                <p class="text-left">Column 4</p>
                              </th>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </th>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </center>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Is this what you're trying to do? https://jsfiddle.net/y942uoLc/1/

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. In this case: remove some code, see if problem persists, repeat. When code is much smaller, edit your question with it.

Comment: Are you aware that many email clients won't allow external CSS classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is padding of `<th>` of the table.

You can write this. It will fix it.

```
table th, table td {
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

These are causing the white spaces :)

```
td.large-4.first, th.large-4.first {
      padding-left: 16px;
}
td.large-4, th.large-4 {
      width: 177.33333px;
      padding-left: 8px;
      padding-right: 8px;
}
th.columns, th.column {
     margin: 0 auto;
     Margin: 0 auto;
     padding-left: 16px;
     padding-bottom: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your css has:

```
table.body .columns {
    padding-left: 16px !important
}
```

can you remove the !important and then do

```
table.body .columns:first-child {
    padding-left: 0;
}
```